# Alle Rechte sind vorbehalten (aber wem?)

Tags: meaning-in-context

Ich versuche gerade ein Dokument zu verstehen, das folgenden Satz enthält:

> Alle Rechte, insbesondere die des Nachdrucks, der Fotokopie, der
> elektronischen Verwendung und der Übersetzung, jeweils auszugsweise
> oder vollständig, sind vorbehalten.

Für mich fehlt hier die wesentliche Information, wem diese Rechte vorbehalten sind. Dem Herausgeber oder den Käufern des Dokuments?
Oder ist das eine übliche Formulierung die ich nicht verstehe?

Comment: Natürlich dem Urheber. Ja, das ist eine übliche Formulierung („all rights reserved“ gibt es übrigens im Englischen auch) und bedeutet, dass der Käufer nur das Recht zur Benutzung erworben hat, aber keine weiteren Rechte an dem Werk.

Comment: Ich kann nicht erkennen, inwiefern der Rechteinhaber die **wesentliche Information** ist.  Wesentlich ist, dass für den geneigten Leser Fotokopie, elektronische Verwendung etc. verboten sind und erst nach Abschluss eines Lizenzabkommens legal werden. Die Angabe, wer dafür zu kontaktieren ist, halte ich für sekundär.

Comment: Es steht ja nur dort, dass es eine Gruppe von Menschen gibt, die das exclusive Recht haben Fotokopien zu erstellen etc. Der geneigte Leser weiß aber nicht ob er zu dieser Gruppe gehört oder nicht, da diese nicht genannt wird. Daher finde ich diese Information schon wesentilch.

Comment: Das *wem* ist ja offensichtlich: dem Eigentümer der Rechte, und der wird's wohl wissen. Genauso ist es aber auch relativ egal, denn das Entscheidende daran ist ja: "Du nicht!".

Comment: Fotokopie, elektronische Verwendung und Übersetzung kann man m.W. nicht wirksam untersagen. Lediglich das in den Verkehr bringen der Fotokopien, Zugang für Dritte zu Digitalisierungen oder öffentliche Aufführungen der Übersetzung.

Comment: Das ist ähnlich wie "Alle Brötchen sind schon gegessen", wo man auch nicht weiß, welcher Schlingel alles aufgegessen hat. Der Schreiber Deines Satzes will uns nicht verraten, wer die Rechte hält. Er will uns nur informieren, dass IRGENDJEMAND die Rechte hat und wir daher  nicht nach Belieben z.B. Kopien machen dürfen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ja, genau, das ist eine übliche, sehr alte Standardformulierung, die aus sich selbst heraus etwas schwer verständlich ist.

Der Text impliziert, dass die Rechte demjenigen vorbehalten bleiben, der die Urheberrechte an dem Text hat oder vom Urheber Rechte am Text erworben hat. "Rechteinhaber" ist der dafür allgemein übliche Begriff im Urheberrecht. Das ist im Allgemeinen der Verlag oder Herausgeber, und der hat diesen Hinweis normalerweise auch dort hineinschreiben lassen (und dabei den Rechteinhaber nicht näher benannt).

Der Leser oder Käufer (m/w/d) hat zwar das Recht, das Werk (Buch, Heft ...) zu lesen oder sein Exemplar weiterzuverkaufen, aber wenn er die Dinge tun will, die dem Rechteinhaber "vorbehalten" sind, braucht er eine Erlaubnis.

Comment: Der Rechteinhaber ist zunächst einmal der Autor des Textes als der Urheber. Eventuell überträgt er einige seiner Rechte an einen Verlag, z. B. um den Text zu publizieren. Von den Rechten, die er nicht überträgt, bleibt er nach wie vor der Rechteinhaber.

Comment: Oder anders gesagt: Im dt. Rechtswesen ist das Urheberrecht per se nicht übertragbar. Entweder man ist der Urheber oder man ist es nicht. Dazu bedarf es keiner Klausel. Die Nutzungsrechte kann man übertragen und der Verwender der Klausel ist - man weiß es nicht, der Verlag, der Autor selbst, ein Mäzen? Meist wird es wohl der Verlag sein.

Comment: @userunknown Das stimmt zwar im engeren Sinn, aber "Nutzungsrechte" ist für die an den Verlag übertragenen Recht auch kein besseres Wort. Das passt eher für Software und dort für den Endnutzer. Es geht ja nicht um die Nutzung des Texts, sondern um die wirtschatliche Verwertung, klassischerweise z.B. durch Drucken. Ich habe mal editiert.

Comment: Nein. Wirtschaftli. Verw. ist nur eine Form der Nutzung, aber die Verw.-rechte sind nicht auf wirtsftl. Nutzung beschränkt. Wenn Du im Stadtpark ein Theater- oder Musikstück aufführst und dafür kein Geld einsammelst ist es immer noch eine N. aber keine wirtsftl. und bedarf einer Lizenz, wenn der Künstler noch nicht so und so lange tot (75 Jahre?) ist (I'ANAL). Umgekehrt darfst Du es im Freundeskreis darbieten und Geld dafür nehmen. Siehe §15 UrhG https://dejure.org/gesetze/UrhG/15.html Oder Du druckst einen Text ab und verteilst ihn gratis öffentlichkeit: verboten. Privat + Gebühr: erlaubt.